# Get all sku for an order through sql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Working on a script to pull some customer order data from various databases and combine them into one output. Most of the stuff works fine, but can't seem to be able to get the sku's for the products of an order.
Noticed there was a meta_key called "_sku" so tried with something like

```
  $sqlMetaSku = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND post_id='$post_id'";
                $resultMetaSku = $conn->query($sqlMetaSku); 
                                
                if ($resultMetaSku->num_rows > 0) { 
                    while($rowMetaSku = $resultMetaSku->fetch_assoc()) {echo($sqlMetaSku);
                        $clientSku = $rowMetaSku["meta_value"]; 
                    
                        echo (between ('s:8:', ';s:12', $clientSku));
                        
                    }
                }
```

but no luck here.
Noticed there was a key called "_order_key" so maybe that's the way to go? I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please add some sample data and also include the output you expect.

Comment: It should be better to save all product skus to the order as custom meta data when order is placed. This way you could get them all very easily.

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: @LoicTheAztec true, but need historic data too. thought it saved the sku's for the order in the database too, but doesn't seem to be the case.